# Qt WinRT Originate Error - 0x40080201

Tags: c++, qt, windows-runtime, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am running into a peculiar issue with a Qt C++ application I am working on. For testing purposes, I tried this with a brand new project and I still get the same exceptions. I am using QFileSystemModel and displaying it inside a QTreeView and it outputs about 28 total errors.

Here's the code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel();
    model->setRootPath("C:\\Users\\Comp\\Desktop\\resume");
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(model->rootPath()));
}
```

A snippet of the error(s) I am getting from the debugger log:

```
Module loaded: C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
Module loaded: C:\WINDOWS\system32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll
onecore\com\combase\catalog\packagedcomcatalog.cpp(1993)\combase.dll!00007FF96C3784A7: (caller: 00007FF96C399D0A) ReturnHr(1) tid(28d8) 80040155 Interface not registered
(28c0.28d8): Windows Runtime Originate Error - code 40080201 (first chance)

Exception at 0x7ff969484008, code: 0x40080201: , flags=0x0 (first chance) in KERNELBASE!RaiseException
onecore\com\combase\catalog\packagedcomcatalog.cpp(1993)\combase.dll!00007FF96C3784A7: (caller: 00007FF96C399D0A) ReturnHr(2) tid(28d8) 80040155 Interface not registered
(28c0.28d8): Windows Runtime Originate Error - code 40080201 (first chance)
```

And this continues for 24 more errors of the same type. Until a bit later, it occurs as:

```
Module loaded: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll
onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(67)\combase.dll!000001D6A186FE7A: (caller: 000001D6A186E2D5) ReturnHr(27) tid(dd4) 80004002 No such interface supported
Module loaded: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2125)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FF96CE14D32: (caller: 00007FF96CE14E96) ReturnHr(1) tid(dac) 8002801D Library not registered.
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2125)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FF96CE14D32: (caller: 00007FF96CE14E96) ReturnHr(2) tid(dac) 8002801D Library not registered.
Module loaded: C:\Windows\System32\OLEACC.dll
```

It seems like the code is fine, as it is working as expected. Does anyone know how to resolve these issues or have any insights?

Comment: I get the same error multiple times for my own Qt WinRT app during compile. `:-1: error: Debugger encountered an exception: Exception at 0x75c81812, code: 0x40080201: , flags=0x0 (first chance)`. Weirdly this is a debugger error but I am compiling the release version. My app is a Qt Quick app and does not use `QTreeView` or `QFileSystemModel` so I think the question is more general and these tags are not necessary.